# Can python add, run & remove a VBA macro to excel without intermediate saving steps?

Tags: python, vba, excel, pandas

I have a long-running python pipeline that generates a pandas dataframe. Briefly, I want to:

1. Display the pandas dataframe in excel
2. Add & run VBA macro
3. Remove VBA macro and save the (newly formatted) output as `.xslx`

The challenge is that I can't figure out how to do this **without an intermediate save-as-`xlsm`-file** step, which is apparently required when adding a VBA macro to an `.xlsx` file. Since this is inefficient, I want to get rid of this intermediate step.

*Here is the code:*

**1. Display the pandas dataframe in excel:**

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
     df_results.to_excel(writer, index = False, sheet_name = "Sheet1")
     #...see below
```

**2A. Add macro and assign .xlsm-filename so that writer can hold macro**

```
     #... see above
     writer.book.filename = 'output.xlsm'           # Add .xlsm filename
     writer.book.add_vba_project('VBA_script.bin')  # This adds my macro
     writer.save()                                  # How to get rid of this step?
```

**2B. Run macro**

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")  # Set up excel
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename = 'output.xlsm')         # Open .xlsm file from step 2A
xl.Application.Run("Module1.Main")                  # Run VBA_macro.bin
```

**3. Remove macro and save to .xlsx**

```
wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs('final_outfile.xlsx', FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2) # Macro disapears here
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
xl = None
```

Is it possible to do this without intermediate .xlsm step & with shorter code?

**How to add, run & remove a VBA macro in an excel context without intermediate saving steps using python?**

Comment: Do you need to add the code to the workbook in question? Otherwise you should be able to have the code in a separate (and probably permanently existing?) .xlsm and modify your .xlsx from there.

Comment: I thought about that - this is what it will boil down to in case the answer to this question here turns out to be "NO"

Comment: why not put the macro code in a second workbook?

Comment: Also, what created `VBA_script.bin`, is there a Python library to do this?

Comment: yes, the script is called VBA_extract.py

Comment: I will follow your suggestions and come back to you later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, create the instance, use the built in VBA Code Import, run macro, save as xlsx to remove macro.

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Add
wb = xl.ActiveWorkbook
wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "Full Path\VBA_script.bin"
xl.Application.Run("Module1.Main")
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.DoNotPromptForConvert = True
wb.CheckCompatibility = False
wb.SaveAs('final_outfile.xlsx', FileFormat=51, ConflictResolution=2) # Macro disapears here
xl.Application.Quit()
del xl
xl = None
```

Comment: Killer. Thanks for your answer - I will test this ASAP and upvote if working

Comment: is there a tools that is available to work with linux? I would like to add a vba script to my excel for example.