# Getting UnicodeDecodeError while reading excel in Tornado,Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, tornado, python-unicode

i'm using postman to send an excel file which i am reading in tornado.

---

#### Tornado code

`self.request.files['1'][0]['body'].decode()`

here if i send **.csv** than, the above code works.

---

if i send **.xlsx** file than i am stuck with this error.

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 10: invalid start byte

---

request.files will fetch the file but the type would be byte. so to convert byte to str i've used decode(), which works only for .csv and not for .xlsx

i tried decode('utf-8') but still no luck.

i've tried searching but didn't find any issue mentioning 0x87 problem?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the `.xlsx` file has a different encoding, not `utf-8`. You'll need to use the original encoding to decode the file.

There's no guaranteed way of finding out the encoding of a file programmatically. I'm guessing you're making this application for general users and so you will keep encountering files with different and unexpected encodings.

A good way to deal with this is by trying to decode using multiple encodings, in case one fails. Example:

```
encodings = ['utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', 'windows-1251', 'windows-1252']

for encoding in encodings:
    try:
        decoded_file = self.request.files['1'][0]['body'].decode(encoding)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # this will run when the current encoding fails
        # just ignore the error and try the next one
        pass
    else:
        # this will run when an encoding passes
        # break the loop
        # it is also a good idea to re-encode the 
        # decoded files to utf-8 for your purpose
        decoded_file = decoded_file.encode("utf8")
        break
else:
    # this will run when the for loop ends
    # without successfully decoding the file
    # now you can return an error message
    # to the user asking them to change 
    # the file encoding and re upload
    self.write("Error: Unidentified file encoding. Re-upload with UTF-8 encoding")
    return

# when the program reaches here, it means 
# you have successfully decoded the file 
# and you can access it from `decoded_file` variable
```

---

Here's a list of some common encodings: [What is the most common encoding of each language?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8528866/1925257)

Comment: Thanks for the idea of multiple encoding.
this .xlsx decodes by 'iso-8859-1' but when i encode by utf-8 
the output is just some random bytes which i don't understand.

I've tried different encoding but still no luck.

can you please try decoding this file?
[test.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10GDlEFpZmOSHAh-kMVEKmL2TZl4IBmkM)

Comment: @MukeshSuthar You're reading the data as plain string (or bytes). You need to treat the data as as xlsx format. But that would be a lot of code to write. Use a library called [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which will help you read the data as xlsx.

Comment: @MukeshSuthar One more thing, if you want to read the data directly from memory without saving to disk first, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667890/1925257).

Comment: Is conversion to CSV an Option (maybe using a python-triggered VBA binary)?

Comment: @xyres EQObject = self.request.files['0'][0]['body'].decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(EQObject)). 

Error: zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad magic number for central directory. 

I dont understand zip error, i'm getting input as byte which is xlsx, and how this zip guy in between poping ambigous errors.

Comment: @mukesh sughar You will find some code to copy and paste on how to read xslx with python in one of my questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/49870991/6060083

Comment: @MukeshSuthar What is `EQObject`? Please open a new question because I don't think this `BadZipFile` error is related to your original question.

Comment: @xyres EQObject is just a variable name to store the xlsx (in byte). and for BadZipFile error ill open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and this worked for me.

```
    import io
    
    df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(self.request.files['1'][0]['body']))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this one, following suggestions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645401/python-pandas-to-excel-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte):

```
self.request.files['1'][0]['body'].decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: try it after removing the first "str" - I have updated my answer accordingly. if this doesn't work, try to remove the second "str" while keeping the first one

Comment: still same error
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'str'
can you tell me why do we need to encode it after decoding?

Comment: just remove all the 'str' - decode/encode is a common conversion flow

Comment: removed all 'str', the code works.
but the output is just some random byte formatted text.
output: \x00\x11\x00\x07\x04\x00\x00\x18K\x00\x00\x00\x00' ... goes-on..

Comment: Ok, so we are one step closer. Let me see what I can do, please give me some short time