# UnicodeDecodeError when trying to operate xlsx file with openpyxl

Tags: python, encoding, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm trying to make my program import data from xlsx file. Here's the part of code:

```
def Volunteer_list_show():
    volunteer_list = load_workbook('Volunteer_list.xlsx')
    surnames = volunteer_list['A']
    names = volunteer_list['B']
    ...
    identificator = volunteer_list['K']
```

And have this type (UnicodeDecodeError) of error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xec in position
> 1: invalid continuation byte

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50713390/getting-unicodedecodeerror-while-reading-excel-in-tornado-python) from other thread:

```
def Volunteer_list_encoding_check(volunteer_list):
    encodings = ['utf-8', 'iso-8859-1', 'windows-1251', 'windows-1252']
    for encoding in encodings:
        try:
            decoded_file = volunteer_list.decode(encoding)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
        else:
            decoded_file = decoded_file.encode("utf-8")
            break
    else:
        print('Not approved encoding')
```

But, I have the same error as first time, even if **def Volunteer_list_show()** is deleted. Opening of workbook via **load_workbook** function alone does not cause problem. Other code checked and does not cause problem.

How to decode-encode xlsx here in UTF-8?

Comment: The traceback is unclear where the problem occurs but it looks unrelated tot he code. The second function looks like nonsense: sequences don't have encodings.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my mistake: you have to work with **active** sheet to take cells or their values, so I've just added this code:

```
volunteer_list_act = volunteer_list.active
```

It works now.